# How to use a variable in Openrowset to Loop over all XML files

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to read an XML file using OpenRowSet from a folder and have been unable to do so and get the error

> *Cannot bulk Load since the "' @FullFilename'' does not exist.*

Would appreciate if one could suggest how I can correct the problem 
to obtain all data from each of the XML files.

Thanks.

Code:

```
declare @Directory varchar(50)
select @Directory = 'E:\XML\'

DECLARE @CD TABLE (XMLData XML);
declare @FileExist int
DECLARE @FileName varchar(500),
@DeleteCommand varchar(1000),
@FullFileName varchar(500)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000),@xml xml

--This is so that we know how long the loop lasts
declare @LoopID int, @MaxID int
SELECT @LoopID = min(id),@MaxID = max(ID)
FROM #tempList

WHILE @LoopID <= @MaxID
BEGIN
    SELECT @FileNAme = filename
    from #tempList
    where id = @LoopID

    SELECT @FullFileName = @Directory + @FileName 
    print @FULLFileName

    exec xp_fileexist @FullFileName , @FileExist output

    if @FileExist =1 --sanity check in case some evil person removed the file
    begin

---********************************Problem with @FullFileName----------------     
    INSERT INTO @CD
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @FullFileName +''' ,Single_BLOB) as rs
---********************************------------

    select * from @CD

    --SET @DeleteCommand = 'del ' +  @Directory + @FileName 
    --maybe you want to delete or move the file to another directory
    -- ** here is how to delete the files you just imported
    -- uncomment line below to delete the file just inserted
    --EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @DeleteCommand
    -- ** end of here is how to delete the files
    end

    --Get the next id, instead of +1 we grab the next value in case of skipped id values
    SELECT @LoopID = min(id)
    FROM #tempList
    where id > @LoopID
END

select * from #tempList
```

This works and I am able to get the XML data from the specified file

```
DECLARE @CD TABLE (XMLData XML);
Declare @get_GeneralID bigint
INSERT INTO @CD
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'E:\XML\TestResult.XML', SINGLE_BLOB) rs;
select * from @CD
```

PS: I have put together from code that I found from the web.

Comment: all the xml files are in `'E:\XML\'` path are have same structure?

Comment: They are of the same format. I get this error: Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
Cannot bulk load. The file "' + @FullFileName +'" does not exist. But with the single file I am able to load the data from the XML file and into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use T-SQL variables in your `OPENROWSET` command - those things need to be fully and explicitly spelled out.

If you need to do this over a list of XML files, you'll have to create your T-SQL command as a string and then use dynamic SQL to execute that command.

Comment: Thanks @Marc_s. I followed your suggestion and am able to load the xml files but have an issue obtaining the values from the nodes.I have posted my sql query along with a sample xml file.